# Shorthand way to remove last forward slash and trailing characters from string

Tags: c#, string

If I have the following string:

> /lorem/ipsum/dolor

and I want this to become:

> /lorem/ipsum

What is the short-hand way of removing the last forward slash, and all characters following it?

I know how I can do this by spliting the string into a `List<>` and removing the last item, and then joining, but is there a shorter way of writing this?

My question is **not** URL specific.

Comment: It will depend on how you want to handle urls like domain.com/ or domain.com/lorem/ipsum/dolor/

Comment: What about `domain.com/lorem/ipsum?path=/`?

Comment: Please ignore the fact its a URL. Theres other logic in place to protect this

Comment: The domains you want are entirely different. One going to direct the user to `dolor` directory the other `ipsum` directory which happens to contain the folder `dolor`.  **What you want is actually not clear.**

Comment: @Ramhound You are making the assumption the return value is for redirection. I don't see where I have implied this.

Comment: @Ramhound I'm pretty sure the OP would be aware of that. And for the record, the *domain* is consistently "domain.com" for both URLs.

Comment: @Ramhound I think I have made myself clear (from the question title alone). For clarity purposes, my question is not URL specific.

Comment: How about `new String("domain.com/lorem/ipsum/dolor".ToCharArray().Reverse().SkipWhile(x => x != '/').Skip(1).Reverse())`? It's not exactly shorthand though :-D

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can use `Substring()` and `LastIndexOf()`:

```
str = str.Substring(0, str.LastIndexOf('/'));
```

**EDIT** (suggested comment)
To prevent any issues when the string may not contain a `/`, you could use something like:

```
int lastSlash = str.LastIndexOf('/');
str = (lastSlash > -1) ? str.Substring(0, lastSlash) : str;
```

Storing the position in a temp-variable would prevent the need to call `.LastIndexOf('/')` twice, but it could be dropped in favor of a one-line solution instead.

Comment: You'll want to check `LastIndexOf` hasn't returned -1 prior to using the result, or else _BANG!_

Comment: @GrantThomas Thanks for the note; I've added a suggested-edit update to my answer to bring notice to this.

Comment: @newfurniturey Thanks! Works a treat. So that i can incorporate all this in the same line (without the need for a `lastSlash` object I've done: `string.Contains("/") ? [your logic] : null`. (I'm happy for a null to be returned if theres no forward slashes). Cheers again!

Answer (score 19):

If there is '/' at the end of the url, remove it.
If not; just return the original one.

```
var url = this.Request.RequestUri.ToString();
url = url.EndsWith("/") ? url.Substring(0, url.Length - 1) : url;
url += @"/mycontroller";
```

Answer (score 9):

One simple way would be

```
    String s = "domain.com/lorem/ipsum/dolor";
    s = s.Substring(0, s.LastIndexOf('/'));
    Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Another maybe

```
String s = "domain.com/lorem/ipsum/dolor";
s = s.TrimEnd('/');
Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Comment: TrimEnd doesn't work. It will remove "/" at the end but it won't remove text after the last appearance.

Answer (score 7):

You can do something like `str.Remove(str.LastIndexOf("/"))`, but there is no built-in method to do what you want.

Edit: you could also use the Uri object to traverse directories, although it does not give exactly what you want:

```
Uri baseUri = new Uri("http://domain.com/lorem/ipsum/dolor");
Uri myUri = new Uri(baseUri, "."); 
// myUri now contains http://domain.com/lorem/ipsum/
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the regex `/[^/]*$` and replace with the empty string:

```
var fixed = new Regex("/[^/]*$").Replace("domain.com/lorem/ipsum/dolor", "")
```

But it's probably overkill here. @newfurniturey's answer of `Substring` with `LastIndexOf` is probably best.

Answer (score 4):

I like to create a String Extension for stuff like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Returns with suffix removed, if present
/// </summary>
public static string TrimIfEndsWith(
    this string value,
    string  suffix)
{
    return  
        value.EndsWith(suffix) ?
            value.Substring(0, value.Length - suffix.Length) :
            value;
}
```

You can then use like this:

```
var myString = "/lorem/ipsum/dolor";
myStringClean = myString.TrimIfEndsWith("/dolor");
```

You now have a re-usable extension across all of your projects that can be used to remove one trailing character or multiple.

Answer (score 4):

```
using System.IO;

mystring.TrimEnd(Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar); // To remove "/"
mystring.TrimEnd(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar); // To remove "\"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        while (input.Last() == '/' || input.Last() == '\\')
        {
            input = input.Substring(0, input.Length - 1);
        }
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explain how it works, and describe when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Curt for your question.
I slightly improved @newfurniturey's code, and here is my version.

```
 if(str.Contains('/')){
      str = str.Substring(0, str.LastIndexOf('/'));
 }
```

Comment: This is clearly not an improvement of code - `str` is unnecessarily iterated twice in your version.

Comment: @maxp, what's your suggestion or what's the best answer here?

Comment: `.Contains()` is doing string iteration, then `LastIndex()` is iterating the same string. Use `LastIndexOf` instead of `.Contains()` (`LastIndexOf` returns -1 if not found - the equivalent of `false`), then re-use the index inside your `Substring()` method. Look at the answer above by @newfurniturey

Answer (score 0):

I'm *way* late to the party, but if you're using C# 8.0+, another clean approach would be to use the range operator:

```
if (urlStr.EndsWith("/")) urlStr = urlStr[..^1];
```

If you're curious as to how this works, take a look at the spec for ranges in C#:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/ranges

**tldr;** `urlStr[..^1]` roughly translates to something along the lines of *"Give me a substring comprised of the characters contained within the range of index 0 to whatever index is 1 away from the last index."*.

In other words, it's similar to...

```
urlStr.Substring(0, urlStr.Length-1)
```